# Gluing morphisms of sheaves on the big zariski site

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, schemes, representable-functor

I have been trying to get used to working with representable functors in place of getting my hands dirty with schemes. In particular I am working on a problem involving blowing up over an arbitrary noetherian scheme X. Let $\mathscr{I} \subseteq \mathcal{O}_{X}$ be a coherent sheaf of ideals. Let $\widetilde{X}$ be the blowing up along $\mathscr{I}$ and let $\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{I})$ be the projective bundle associted to $\mathscr{I}$. I want to think of these simply as objects representing sheaves on the big Zariski site $\text{Sch}/X$.

If we choose an affine cover $\{ U_{i} = \operatorname{Spec}A_{i} \}$ of $X$ then over each $A_{i}$ these schemes look like $\operatorname{Proj}(A_{i} \oplus \mathscr{I}(U_{i}) \oplus \mathscr{I}(U_{i})^{2} \oplus \cdots )$ and $\operatorname{Proj}(\operatorname{Sym}_{A_{i}}(\mathscr{I}(U_{i})))$.

I want to understand how $X$-morphisms $\widetilde{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(\mathscr{I})$ arise by gluing universal properties for the projective spaces over each affine.

My understanding is that the key theorem towards this is the gluing theorem in the stacks project [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04TQ). My main question here is to clarify that I am understanding this result correctly. My understanding is as follows:

Define sheaves on the big Zariski site $\text{Sch}$ (not over $X$) as follows,
$$ \hom(-, \widetilde{X}): \text{Sch} \longrightarrow \text{Set} , \\ \hom(-, \mathbb{P}(\mathscr{I})): \text{Sch} \longrightarrow \text{Set} $$
Then we pullback these sheaves to the localized sites $\text{Sch}/U_{i}$ and assume we have morphisms,
$$
\phi_{i}: \hom(-, \widetilde{X})|_{\text{Sch}/U_{i}} \longrightarrow \hom(-, \mathbb{P}(\mathscr{I})|_{\text{Sch}/U_{i}}
$$
which agree on fibered products (read: intersections). Then the lemma gives us a morphism of sheaves on $\text{Sch}/X$,
$$
\hom(-, \widetilde{X})|_{\text{Sch}/X} \longrightarrow \hom(-, \mathbb{P}(\mathscr{I})|_{\text{Sch}/X}
$$
First of all, is this actually the correct interpretation of the lemma? It just seems odd to me that in order to obtain a morphism over $X$ we have to begin with sheaves on the category of schemes not over $X$. And assuming my interpretation is correct, it is still not completely clear to me that 
$$
 \hom(-, \widetilde{X})|_{\text{Sch}/U_{i}} = \hom_{U_{i}}(-, \widetilde{X} \times_{X} U_{i})
$$
Is that actually true? Obviously I would like that to be true in order to appeal to the mapping properties for Proj over an affine base.